# Jacobian for a system using Matlabs ode23s

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, heat-equation, jacobian

Using the method of lines to the homogenious heat equation $\textbf{u}_t - \textbf{u}_{xx}= 0$ yields the system

$$ \frac{d\textbf{u}}{dt} = A\textbf{u} + \textbf{b}(t) $$

Using ode23s and specifying $A$ as the Jacobian really speeds up the calculations, compared to the regular ode23s.

I've searched some and not found anything, how come the Jacobian for the system is $A$ and why is specifying $A$ as the Jacobian much more efficient?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode23s.html), the Jacobian to pass to `ode23s` is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, where the system is $y'=f(t,y)$. It seems to match what you did. As to the faster calculations: I don't know the specifics of the `ode23s` method, but we may assume that if the Jacobian is not provided, an approximation is made, or a suboptimal method is used instead: this could explain the difference. You can check the source code, if it's provided (it's usually provided for functions that are written in MATLAB).